# In Android which is faster ui in terms of performance ui created in xml or ui created with java code

Tags: android

Can any body let me know that which is the good way of creating UI for android apps, creating UI in XML or creating UI in java code, and also will the performance of app be affected by any of these techniques.

Comment: Worrying about this falls under the category of "premature optimization". If you have an Android app with performance issues, use tools like Traceview to determine the specific sources of your problems. Until then, in the absence of other compelling reasons, stick to the patterns that most developers use... and most developers create their UI definitions as layout XML resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory, the native code will be faster. I'm not sure how much faster it is in real life, because if you create  a layout natively, you have to make a bunch of method calls to setup your views, while XML uses the AttributeSet to set the properties.

Personally, I don't think the performance benefit (if any) outweighs the readability of using the XML layouts. For example, you can define a method to call with the `onClick` attribute in XML, but in code, you have to define a `OnClickListener` object, often as an anonymous inner class. The XML onClick makes it much easier to find things in code.

Answer (score 0):

Although i never tested, i'd guess that creating the same UI in Java code would be a bit faster than creating it on XML. But the performance benefit of doing such thing is probably negligible and using XML Layouts will get your UI done faster, with cleaner code, easier to maintain and more flexible.

As you can see the upsides of using XML are much greater than downsides. So, i'd say the best practice is using XML.